# Stitching images with high resolution

Tags: opencv, image-stitching

I'm trying to stitch 2 images with resolution 3000x4000 using Stitcher class and it just crashes. I tried to use multiple parameters, sometimes it says insufficient memory and sometimes it just crashes instantly.

I uploaded my images so you could see what i'm trying to stitch.

[top image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORAmR.jpg)

[bottom image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl4vs.jpg)

I was doing stitching with just following code:

```
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(false);
stitcher.stitch(images, result);
```

All of my images with lower resolution (1980x1000) were stitched correctly.

Now i tried this with setting wave correction to false, or setting resolution parameters to -1 but nothing helped.

I'm also running this code on PC with 4GB RAM, but i'm not sure if this is the problem. Is it possible to stitch those images into one correctly using stitcher class?

EDIT: I'm using opencv 2.4.13 in Visual Studio(windows 64bit)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("top.jpg");
    cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("bottom.jpg");

    std::vector <cv::Mat> imgs;
    imgs.push_back(img1);
    imgs.push_back(img2);

    cv::Mat pano; 

    cv::Stitcher stitcher = cv::Stitcher::createDefault(false); 
    cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano); 

    cv::imwrite("stitched.jpg", pano); // write the result to the output image

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [MCVE], please :) Emphasis on the **complete**, meaning something we can compile without any significant additions/modifications to reproduce the problem. | What OpenCV version? What platform (OS,  32bit or 64bit)? What compiler?

Comment: i added code and the info

Comment: OK, and your application, is it 32bit or 64bit? (You'd choose that in MSVS)

Comment: it's 64bit and i'm running it as Release

Comment: @DanMašek could you please try that code with those 2 images? i'd like to know if that memory problem might be because of my PC

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce any out of memory issues, the stitcher always just returns Status `ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS`.

Comment: after resizing them to 800x1066 i got a acceptable result

Comment: I would suggest breaking the problem down when working with images of such a massive size. Reduce the resolution and find the keypoints and matches. Then find the homography which can be applied to the higher res images still as they are still using the same reference planes used to get the homography.